# Q: What method to use for cluster analysis?

Tags: clustering, variance, standard-deviation, methodology

I am in pickle when it comes to choose what statistical method I should be using for my data..

At the moment I am working with analyzing clonal heterogeneity in tumors using a new approach. Basically we are using 2D scatterplots to analyze clusters  that represent biological events using a visual heuristic approach, like:

[image]

As you can see the dots are generally clustering into groups with some outliers, however, this is **greatly correlated with quality of data**.
(The paper from where the figure is from can be found [here](http://www.oncotarget.com/index.php?journal=oncotarget&page=article&op=view&path%5B%5D=15014&path%5B%5D=47972)). I've looked into k-mean cluster analysis, but I don't always know how many clusters we are looking for.

What I had in mind was calculating the x and y mean of each cluster, and calculate some kind of variance/strength. Then compare the same clusters when the data is of lower quality to see how much the variance/strength has increased.

I am unsure what kind of statistics I should be using, mutations are occurring at random, standard error of mean etc. would not work AFAIK. I have looked into Poisson distribution but that is more when trying to calculate the chance of a random event occurring.

Sorry for the long question, I hope you can point me in the right direction! Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Clearly a **density based** approach like DBSCAN and OPTICS will be closest to your intuition.

Nevertheless, I don't think you gain anything by replying on an algorithm here over just continuing to pick clusters yourself. Humans are pretty good at arguing what a pattern is in 2d data - probably better than the algorithms.